# Geopandas geometry to geojson in geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I have a geopandas object and I want to conver geometry to string. Normaly geometry is like below

```
file = geopandas.read_file("test.TAB")
# its content is 

ID                                                            ***
MI_PRINX                                                      ***9.0

geometry                POLYGON ((4496597.53 4537154.3691, 4496022.574... 
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I little bit blured the data as it is private. As it is seen, geometry is object of shapely.Polygon and I want to change it by its geojson format.

```
Polygon(...)
```

If I write something like below

```
file.iloc[0].geometry = geopandas.GeoSeries(file.iloc[0]).geometry.to_json()
```

I got this error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  file.loc[0].geometry = "something"
```

I want to have a data like that:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[4496597.53, 4537154.3691], [4496022.574, 4537169.5574], [4495738.723, 4537227.9468], [4495722.012, 4537167.8742], [4495576.619, 4536541.8022], [4495762.527, 4536487.3604], [4495791.462, 4536284.4807], [4495800.719, 4536212.8866], [4495810.617, 4536200.223], [4495837.107, 4536191.6469], [4495838.469, 4536186.0163], [4495795.469, 4536178.2817], [4495750.385, 4536174.0539], [4495724.456, 4536165.7583], [4495684.381, 4536143.9576], [4495678.931, 4536140.9919], [4495702.776, 4536145.22], [4495729.345, 4536153.7961], [4495771.905, 4536163.3739], [4495803.284, 4536165.8987], [4495842.678, 4536165.3376], [4495891.008, 4536160.1279], [4495943.867, 4536151.6919], [4496009.109, 4536152.2532], [4496096.593, 4536148.5863], [4496453.701, 4536103.3015], [4496597.53, 4537154.3691]]]}, "bbox": [4495576.619, 4536103.3015, 4496597.53, 4537227.9468]}], "bbox": [4495576.619, 4536103.3015, 4496597.53, 4537227.9468]}
```

I dont want to create new dataframe as its size is so big. Is there any way to do ?

Comment: note that a setting with copy warning is a *warning* not an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Yes but actual data is not changed even it is just warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**geo_interface**](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.__geo_interface__.html) method may help you. It returns the geometries in the form of a dictionary.

```
file = file.__geo_interface__
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of to_geojson, you can convert all geometry columns to well known text with [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_wkt`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_wkt.html):

```py
file = file.to_wkt()
```

Comment: I did it but nothing changed

Comment: I added desired data type to the question